# Why can't I type simple formulas when using transforms?

Tags: 3d-view, mathematics

what its happening here? i just want to rotate `R 360/5` but if do that the math function turns in to something like `R [1/(360)]` 
even more if i divide by one i get 3282.81º

if i want to do a simple math i need to do  `R ** <backspace> 360/5` and that way works, but versions ago I only need to type `R 360/5` and that was it.

I remember something about this change months ago but i really don't understand it and also didn't find anything at the reference.

[image]

> Rotation
>   To specify a value for clockwise rotation, press R, (0 - 9), then Return to confirm. To specify counter-clockwise rotation press R, Minus, (kbd:0 - 9), then Return to confirm. Note that 270 degrees of clockwise rotation is equivalent to -90 degrees of counter-clockwise rotation.
>
> source:
>   https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/numeric_input.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Activate formula mode for the Numeric input

That's because currently the "formula" input (advanced mode) is **not** active by default. This was made to preserve some old functionalities, like the <kbd>/</kbd> shortcut that, as in your case, transforms the number to its inverse.

The rule is that the formula mode becomes active only once the <kbd>Numpad *</kbd> (or the <kbd>=</kbd>) key has been pressed, so in your case you can type

<kbd>Numpad *</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

Or

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>Numpad *</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>Numpad *</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

<kbd>3</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Numpad *</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>

and all should work as expected.

---

[Here](https://youtu.be/XwjKSiKwGTw?t=2m46s) you can find the Sneak Peek video made by [Plasmasolutions](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQB_JPnenWON0sB3QBoGx-Q) about the topic.

And here's some lines from the [2.70 release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.70/UI) abot the UI (see *Transform Tools Number Input* section):

> Number input for tools (when you grab an object for example, you can type indirectly values with the keyboard) has been reworked, you can now use units and Python expressions in it. ([87cc890aef53](https://developer.blender.org/rB87cc890aef53)).
>
> We have **two "modes"**, simple and advanced ones, **use '=' or 'pad*' to
>   enable advanced mode**, and 'ctrl-=' or 'ctrl-pad*' to switch back to
>   simple mode.
>
> Simple mode works nearly like it did before, it only accepts simple
>   numbers, and you can still use '-' to negate and '/' to inverse the
>   value (as well as non-number input shortcuts like XYZ, RSG, etc.).
>   Compared to Blender 2.69 behavior, you can now copy and paste
>   expressions, and navigate in the number you typed, so you can for
>   example fix a typo without having to type everything again.
>
> In advanced mode, we gain more power and flexibility, but lose a few
>   "shortcuts" like '-' to negate, or '/' to inverse

---

The **3282.81° issue** can be explained with the fact that Blender makes some conversions between radiants and degree that, in conbination with the inverse operation, led to an apparently unexpected results.

By default the input for rotation are considered as degree (1° in the depicted case). In randiants would be:

```
rad(1°) = 0,0174532925199433
```

When you press <kbd>/</kbd> Blender uderstand that it has to caluculate the inverse of your input, so it switchs to radiants to perform the operations. The resulting input now  is

```
1/0,0174532925199433 = 57,2957795130823
```

And only at this point he perform the degree conversion:

```
deg(57,2957795130823) = 3282,80635001174°
```

To avoid this kind of I would suggest to use the **advanced mode**, where you get expected results:

<kbd>*</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>1</kbd>

[image]

Comment: aah rigth, now i remember, thanks.
now im trying to understand this a bit better, i would think that 360/5 its a simple formula but as you comment advanced mode its not active by default, so in the default mode, what is the simpliest thing that can i do? 
typing 0 to 9 doesn't do much

Comment: Glad it helped! Sorry but I didn't get the last part of your comment. The simplest thing that you can do for...for doing what?

Comment: to do something,  R>45 intro  rotates 45 degres that is simple and works, further than that what is it posible to do with the math mode by default? 1/(1)=3282.81º dosn't have any sence to me, i look for it together with "degrees" "radians"  "geometry" "math"   and didn't get a plausible result to it.
the thing is that in mi mind X/Y or X-Y is the simplest thing i can think o and here, in simple mode(the default if i got it right) that doesn't work

Comment: As the explanation was quite long, I put that in the answer. In the Simple mode you can only Inverse (/) or the Negate (-) the input number, while in Advanced mode you can write expressions (e.g. 2**2+62*52*(522+6)...), use functions (e.g. sin()...) and use math constants (e.g. pi, e...)

Comment: The mayor benifits comes from the use of "negation". I often start typing the value without minding the value sign, as I can press "-" anytime to adjust the direction. In advanced mode I would need to navigate till the beginning of the number, slowing me down. I must  admit that the use of "/" its a little bit trickier, I probably never used that in simple mode.